# Reverse traits lookup?

Tags: c++

I have been looking for a design that solves the following problem.
It will take a few words to describe.

We have four types A1, A2, B, and C.

We would like to write a function fn that takes as parameter a type P.
Using traits, P resolves within A1/A2/B/C to PA1/PA2/PB/PC.

The implementation of fn is the same for PA1 and PA2, but it is
different for PB and PC, both between them as well as from that of
PA1/PA2.

```
#include <cassert>

struct PA1 {};
struct PA2 {};
struct PB  {};
struct PC  {};

struct A1 { typedef PA1 P; };
struct A2 { typedef PA2 P; };
struct B  { typedef PB  P; };
struct C  { typedef PC  P; };

template<typename T> char fn(typename T::P)
{
    return 'a';
}

char fn(B::P) {   return 'b';  }
char fn(C::P) {   return 'c';  }

int main()
{
    PA1 pa1;
    PA2 pa2;
    PB  pb;
    PC  pc;
    assert( fn<A1>(pa1) == 'a' );
    assert( fn<A2>(pa2) == 'a' );

    assert( fn(pb) == 'b' );
    assert( fn(pc) == 'c' );
}
```

The advantage of the code above is that the implementation of fn for
PA1 and PA2 is not repeated.

But here is the snag. The function calls are not symmetric. It is

```
fn<A1>(pa1)
```

and

```
fn<A2>(pa2)
```

for A1/A2/PA1/PA2, but just `fn(pb)` and
`fn(pc)` for B/C/PB/PC.

This precludes using fn(..) within yet another (not shown) class
template.

Normally this is not an issue. The template parameter can be deduced
for parameterized functions. That doesn't work here. We'd be asking
the compiler to locate the type among A1/A2/B/C for which P resolves
to one of PA1/PA2/PB/PC.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are confusing two things here:

> The implementation of `fn` is the same for both `PA1` and `PA2`

Does not preclude `PA1` and `PA2` from being distinct types with distinct `typedef`.

Which we can therefore use as is:

```
template <typename PA>
char fn(PA pa) {
  typedef typename PA::type Type; // A1 or A2
  return 'a';
}

char fn(PB);
char fn(PC);
```

If you cannot actually modify `P` itself, you can always introduce a traits class.

```
template <typename T>
struct PTraits;

template <>
struct PTraits<PA1> { typedef A1 type; };

template <>
struct PTraits<PA2> { typedef A2 type; };

// ...
```

I would note that Herb Sutter recommend not to use function specializations and to prefer overload, because the interaction between overload (esp. with template involved) is specialization is extremely tricky... and it's hard to fathom which function will get called from a given set of parameters.

Comment: Modifying every part is possible, so that's not an issue.  But first.. I don't see the use for `typedef typename PA::type Type;`. Could you explain how the `typedef` would help in resolving the overload between PA1::P and PA2::P?

Comment: @user704972: you don't overload between `PA1::P` and `PA2::P` but between `PA1` and `PA1`, since the function has the same implementation for both. The `typedef` is just so that you can get access back to the original type `A1` or `A2` instead of passing it as a template parameter to the function. This, in turn, harmonize the calls.

Comment: I'm amazed! That's indeed the simplest design possible. Template template parameters are still needed (I'd include the final code if the interface here would let me), but there is no need for either specializations or for wrapper classes (compare with the discussion at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644448/specialization-of-template-template-parameters).

Comment: @matthieu-m: could you take a look at the sequel at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646665/transforming-a-parameterization-by-two-classes-to-a-parameterization-by-one-class` if you have a chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really have the compiler go in reverse; what happens if two structs have `P` as a `typedef` for `int`?

If you **do** have a one to one mapping of `T` to `T::P`, then you will need to tell the compiler how to go from `T::P` back to `T` explicitly.

Comment: You're right; in general it's not possible. So what would do for the four function calls to be all fn(...) or all fn<..>(...), but not a mixture of the two?

Answer (score 0):

To keep things symmetric you could use template specialisation:

```
template<> char fn<B>(B::P) {   return 'b';  }
template<> char fn<C>(C::P) {   return 'c';  }
```

then your calls would all look like:

```
assert( fn<B>(pb) == 'b' );
assert( fn<C>(pc) == 'c' );
```

Interestingly, even with explicit template instantiation like:

```
template char fn<A1>(A1::P);
template char fn<A2>(A2::P);
```

we don't get inferred types.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Now suppose that each of the eight classes is itself parameterized. We can write the function fn using template template parameters, but it's not clear how the syntax for the specialization should then be. Let me post the sequel as a question titled 'Specialization of template template parameters'.