# Specialization of template template parameters

Tags: c++

This is a sequel question (on a different topic) to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642819/reverse-traits-lookup). The code below incorporates Dehstil's suggestion to use specialization.

How should a function that has template template parameters be specialized?

The code below (in which the two specialization lines do not compile) make the question concrete.

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename S> struct PA1 {};
template<typename S> struct PA2 {};
template<typename S> struct PB  {};
template<typename S> struct PC  {};

template<typename S> struct A1 { typedef PA1<S> P; };
template<typename S> struct A2 { typedef PA2<S> P; };
template<typename S> struct B  { typedef PB <S> P; };
template<typename S> struct C  { typedef PC <S> P; };

template<typename S, template<typename> class T> char fn(typename T<S>::P);

template<typename S, template<typename> class T> char fn(typename T<S>::P)
{
    return 'a';
}

template<typename S> char fn<B<S> >(B<S>::P) {   return 'b';  }
template<typename S> char fn<C<S> >(C<S>::P) {   return 'c';  }

int main()
{
    PA1<int> pa1;
    PA2<int> pa2;
    PB<int>  pb;
    PC<int>  pc;
    assert( (fn<int, A1>(pa1)) == 'a' );
    assert( (fn<int, A2>(pa2)) == 'a' );

    assert( (fn<int, B>(pb)) == 'b' );
    assert( (fn<int, C>(pc)) == 'c' );
}
```

It's important for the four function calls fn<...,...>() to have identical signatures when called since they will themselves reside in a template class that applies to the four classes A1/A2/B/C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial Specialization of function template is NOT allowed by the C++ Standard!

Overload your functions instead of specializing them.

Read the explanation as to [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) **by Herb Sutter**

Then read why to overload than specialize : [Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) **by Herb Sutter**

---

## How to call all functions uniformly if you overload

Write a class template `call` and specialize them as:

```
template<class S, template<typename> class T>
struct call
{
    static char fn(typename T<S>::P &p)
    {
         return ::fn<S,T>(p);
    }
};
 
template<class S>
struct call<S,B>
{
    static char fn(typename B<S>::P &p)
    {
         return ::fn<S>(p);
    }
};
 
template<class S>
struct call<S,C>
{
    static char fn(typename C<S>::P &p)
    {
         return ::fn<S>(p);
    }
};
```

Then you can use this class template to call all the functions uniformly as:

```
assert( (call<int, A1>::fn(pa1)) == 'a' );
assert( (call<int, A2>::fn(pa2)) == 'a' );

assert( (call<int, B>::fn(pb)) == 'b' );
assert( (call<int, C>::fn(pc)) == 'c' );
```

See the online demo : http://www.ideone.com/TISIT

Note also the overloaded function templates in the complete solution at ideone.com (above link)

Comment: The signatures become different, which precludes using fn in a generic class!

Comment: @user704972: the overload can have same name; in fact that is what overload means.

Comment: What I mean is this. Suppose we now have a `template<typename T> struct Foo { void g(...) { ... fn()... } };` where T can be any of A1/A2/B/C. Since fn() appears in one form only (for instance, as either fn<T>() or fn()), its definition for the four types must also be identical.

Comment: @user704972: See my answer. I updated it with how to call all the functions uniformly if you overload the function template.

Comment: We're closing in! An otherwise unnecessary wrapper class is not a bad price to pay, but why use a static function and deal with the ugly syntax? What about using fn as the name of the class (instead of call) and defining a function object? Will the (unnecessary) object not also be allocated statically and have little to no cost compared to static functions?

Comment: @user704972 : Not directly related to your question or this answer, but if you want to work with templates **at all** on any non-trivial level, you had better learn to love "unnecessary wrapper classes". ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn : Point well taken. :)    Still, the presence of function objects is meant to alleviate the ugliness of the unnecessary tidbits a little bit, no?

Comment: @user704972: That is not *unnecessary wrapper*. That is necessary if you want to call all the functions **uniformly**. Also, `fn` function inside the `call` class template is static so that you can call it **without creating an instance** of `call` class. Second, if you're using templates and want to treat all different things uniformly, then you have to love such *ugly syntax*.

Comment: @user704972 : To the library user, sure. To the library *writer* (i.e., you in this case), not really.

Comment: @user704972: function objects require you to create objects of the classes; only then they're useful. However, for `static` functions, you don't need to create any object. You can use the syntax `className::StaticFunction()` to call the static function.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for your help. This is already a good solution, but I nevertheless am trying to find a design based on functions alone. Take a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646665/transforming-a-parameterization-by-two-classes-to-a-parameterization-by-one-class` for a related question.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be only fully specialized. Use function overloading:

```
template<typename S> char fn(typename B<S>::P) {   return 'b';  }
template<typename S> char fn(typename C<S>::P) {   return 'c';  }
```

Comment: Once I use overloading, it becomes impossible to use fn inside a generic class. The four calls to fn with the four types must have the same signature.

Comment: @user704972 : This answer has the correct syntax; show us the cases where it's "impossible to use `fn`".

Comment: `template<typename T> struct Action { Action() {}; char g(T::P p) { return fn(p); } };`

Comment: It should be `char g(typename T::P p)`.