# Transforming a parameterization by two classes to a parameterization by one class

Tags: c++

The following code has a little bit of unpleasantness.

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename S> struct PA1 {}; template<typename S> struct QA1 {};
template<typename S> struct PA2 {}; template<typename S> struct QA2 {};
template<typename S> struct PB  {}; template<typename S> struct QB  {};
template<typename S> struct PC  {}; template<typename S> struct QC  {};

template<typename S> struct A1 { typedef PA1<S> P; typedef QA1<S> Q; };
template<typename S> struct A2 { typedef PA2<S> P; typedef QA2<S> Q; };
template<typename S> struct B  { typedef PB<S>  P; typedef QB<S>  Q; };
template<typename S> struct C  { typedef PC<S>  P; typedef QC<S>  Q; };

template<typename PA, typename QA>
char fn(PA, QA) {
    return 'a';
}

template<typename S> char fn(PB<S>, QB<S>) { return 'b'; }
template<typename S> char fn(PC<S>, QC<S>) { return 'c'; }

template<typename T>
struct Action
{
    char z;
    Action(typename T::P p, typename T::Q q)
    {
        z = fn(p, q);
    }
};

int main()
{
    PA1<int> pa1; QA1<int> qa1;
    PA2<int> pa2; QA2<int> qa2;
    PB<int>  pb;  QB<int>  qb;
    PC<int>  pc;  QC<int>  qc;

    assert( fn(pa1, qa1) == 'a' );
    assert( fn(pa2, qa2) == 'a' );

    assert( fn(pb, qb) == 'b' );
    assert( fn(pc, qc) == 'c' );

    Action<A1<int> > aa1 = Action<A1<int> >(pa1, qa1);    assert( aa1.z == 'a' );
    Action<A2<int> > aa2 = Action<A2<int> >(pa2, qa2);    assert( aa2.z == 'a' );

    Action<B<int> > ab = Action<B<int> >(pb, qb );    assert( ab.z == 'b' );
    Action<C<int> > ac = Action<C<int> >(pc, qc );    assert( ac.z == 'c' );
}
```

Even though PA and QA always arise in tandem (PA1 with QA1 and PA2 with QA2), we write

```
template<typename PA, typename QA>
char fn(PA, QA) { ... }
```

It would be much nicer to write

```
template<typename A>
char fn(typename A::P, typename A::Q) {
    return 'a';
}
```

Can you suggest a modification that would make that possible?

Comment: I don't really see the issue with having to write the function with 2 template parameters instead of one. After all, you do write it with 2 arguments.

Comment: Also, you cannot specialize if you attempt to change, this breaks your requirement, furthermore the calling syntax will not be as clean as it is now - all-in-all, leave exactly as is...

Comment: I do not want to give the client the impression that it is all right to call fn with two parameters of type PA1 and QA2. It would be much worse if such a call happened to compile. Using `template<typename A>` is a way both to give a signal about what is legal, as well as to make the illegal use impossible by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question and its predecessors, the task is a specialization of function template on a class template regardless of its template parameter.

Generic solution:

```
#include <cassert>
//remember the value of the argument S to retrieve it later
template<typename S> struct PA1 { typedef S S; };
template<typename S> struct PA2 { typedef S S; };
template<typename S> struct PB  { typedef S S; };
template<typename S> struct PC  { typedef S S; };

//helper: generic version of fn for any parameters except PB и PC
template<typename T, typename S>
struct FN
{
    static char fn() { return 'a'; }
};
//helper: fn specialized for class template PB
template<typename S>
struct FN<PB<S>, S>
{
    static char fn() { return 'b'; }
};
//helper: fn specialized for class template PC
template<typename S>
struct FN<PC<S>, S>
{
    static char fn() { return 'c'; }
};

//fn relies on compiler's type deduction to avoid specifying of template parameter explicitly
template<typename T>
char fn(T t)
{
    return FN< T, T::S>::fn();
}
//usage
int main()
{
    PA1<int> pa1;
    PA2<char> pa2;
    PB<float>  pb;
    PC<double>  pc;
    assert( (fn(pa1)) == 'a' );
    assert( (fn(pa2)) == 'a' );
    assert( (fn(pb)) == 'b' );
    assert( (fn(pc)) == 'c' );
}
```

Applying this method to your case:

```
#include <cassert>

template<typename S> struct PA1 { typedef S S; }; template<typename S> struct QA1 {};
template<typename S> struct PA2 { typedef S S; }; template<typename S> struct QA2 {};
template<typename S> struct PB  { typedef S S; }; template<typename S> struct QB  {};
template<typename S> struct PC  { typedef S S; }; template<typename S> struct QC  {};

template<typename S> struct A1 { typedef PA1<S> P; typedef QA1<S> Q; };
template<typename S> struct A2 { typedef PA2<S> P; typedef QA2<S> Q; };
template<typename S> struct B  { typedef PB<S>  P; typedef QB<S>  Q; };
template<typename S> struct C  { typedef PC<S>  P; typedef QC<S>  Q; };

template<typename T, typename S>
struct FN
{
    static char fn() { return 'a'; }
};
template<typename S>
struct FN<PB<S>, S>
{
    static char fn() { return 'b'; }
};
template<typename S>
struct FN<PC<S>, S>
{
    static char fn() { return 'c'; }
};

template<typename A>
char fn() //or char fn(A* a)
{
    return FN<A::P, A::P::S>::fn();
}

template<typename T>
struct Action
{
    char z;
    //so the constructor accepts only correct combinations of p and q 
    Action(typename T::P p, typename T::Q q)
    {
        z = fn<T>(); //or fn((T*)NULL);
    }
};    
int main()
{
    PA1<int> pa1; QA1<int> qa1;
    PA2<int> pa2; QA2<int> qa2;
    PB<int>  pb;  QB<int>  qb;
    PC<int>  pc;  QC<int>  qc;

    Action<A1<int> > aa1 = Action<A1<int> >(pa1, qa1);    assert( aa1.z == 'a' );
    Action<A2<int> > aa2 = Action<A2<int> >(pa2, qa2);    assert( aa2.z == 'a' );

    Action<B<int> > ab = Action<B<int> >(pb, qb );    assert( ab.z == 'b' );
    Action<C<int> > ac = Action<C<int> >(pc, qc );    assert( ac.z == 'c' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want type `A` to be automatically inferred, then no such modification is possible unless you have `fn` take an argument of type `A` (or `A&` or `A*` etc) and consequently force the user to pass in a value of that type.

On the other hand, if you don't mind forcing the caller to specify the template argument explicitly, then that syntax is already fine.

There's no happy medium.

Comment: It's all right to use the class A to instantiate either fn or Action, or both, but A's sole reason for existence is to be a container for multiple types (P, Q, ...). Creating an object of type A would be awkward. In other words, writing fn<A>(...) is fine, but writing fn(Aobj) is clumsy.

Comment: @user704972 : That being the case, `template<typename A> char fn(typename A::P, typename A::Q) { return 'a'; }` as you proposed in the question is just fine, no?

Answer (score 0):

C++0x will have [template aliases](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#template-alias)

Oh and to track when it comes to GNU C++: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html